# Microservice architecture with Auth Server and Proxy using .net core

Tags: .net-core, microservices, reverse-proxy, openiddict

I want to develop a microservices architecture with an OAuth server (using openiddict). My front-end applications are Android and Angular. All other protected APIs should be behind a proxy as their endpoints cannot be exposed to clients directly. My main question is for getting the Access token from Auth server should the client applications call the Auth server via proxy OR first to obtain the ticket / Auth code they hit the Auth server directly and after receiving the token they call other resource APIs via proxy.

Approach 1:
Client -> Proxy -> Auth Server (Get the ticket)
Client (with ticket) -> Proxy -> User Service

Approach 2:
Client -> Auth Server (exposed endpoint)
Client (with ticket) -> Proxy -> User Service

Any guiding principal will be of great help

I have read many articles regarding openid and YARP proxy and have implemented them to some extent but this approach is not clicking for me. Although I have read many samples but not been able to figure out the best option